# system() and shell_exec() methods

Tags: php, windows, pdf, html-generation

I am working with a WAMP installation (on Windows).
Do the methods `system()` and `shell_exec()` only work on Linux machine or are they available on Windows, too? I am trying these methods in Windows but nothing is working.

Comment: They work on windows, what can only mean, that you did something wrong. You should clarify your question.

Comment: i used pdftohtml converter from from the link http://www.articlediary.com/article/php-script-for-pdf-to-html-conversion-125.html they used system() method in it it doesnt work for me. can u please help me in it

Comment: We can, but the code (in form of an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), maybe in a new question) will get you way better answers than "please help me" - *we don't know what exactly to help you with*.

Comment: Without any code or error/notice/unexpected behavior is nearly impossible to find the problem.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in the documentation for [`system`](http://php.net/system) and [`shell_exec`](http://php.net/shell_exec), both are supported on all platforms php runs on (otherwise there'd be a notice).

Answer (score 1):

Both functions work on Windows, but there is another security restriction -
you need to disable [safe_mode](http://php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php) first. You can do this in your php.ini file.

Answer (score 0):

For questions like that the first thing you should of done was look up the documentation found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php), where you will find that it doesn't explicitly say its Linux only. The issue you could be having is PHP is in safemode or you need to add rights to CMD for the account php uses.